# MySQL reverse GROUP BY results

Tags: mysql

I'm not good at Mysql expressions, so here is a quick question that I'm trying to get my head around. I would like to reverse the order of the **GROUP BY** expression so that I can get the last entry by the user.

I managed to find good examples around the internet, but I couldn't implement them with my expression without receiving an error. Thanks guys!

```
SELECT messages.conv, messages.from_user, messages.to_user,
        messages.content, messages.date_posted, messages.note_read,
        messages.active, users.thumb, users.name, users.id
FROM `messages` 
INNER JOIN `users` 
    ON messages.from_user = users.id 
WHERE messages.from_user = 1 
    OR messages.to_user = 1 
GROUP BY messages.conv 
ORDER BY date_posted ASC
```

Comment: There is no error, I just want to have the LAST entry in the GROUPED BY rows. By default GROUP BY takes the first as the base to which it groups the entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I apparently misunderstood your requirement, your current query will return a pseudo-random row due to your `GROUP BY` not having any aggregates, what you want is the last row for each conversation which would be something more like (assuming `messages`, like `users`, has an autoincrementing primary key called `id`);

```
SELECT messages.conv, messages.from_user, messages.to_user,
       messages.content, messages.date_posted, 
       messages.note_read, messages.active, users.thumb, 
       users.name, users.id FROM  `messages` 
INNER JOIN  `users` 
       ON messages.from_user = users.id 
WHERE messages.id IN
      (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages 
       WHERE messages.from_user = 1 OR messages.to_user = 1 
       GROUP BY conv);
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab060/5).

Comment: Also, omit the `GROUP BY` as there is no aggregate function like `COUNT`, `SUM`, `MIN` or `MAX`.

Comment: @KenKeenan Good point, I always forget that MySQL allows `GROUP BY` without aggregate functions.

Comment: i need the group by to take the last entry in the DB, its nothing to do with the ORDER BY. Thats the problem

Comment: @Ando, why not use the `LIMIT` clause?

Comment: @KenKeenan because there are many messages which follow a type of pattern which is in the conv column and I'm not familiar with a way to list all the different conversations and then sort them by date so that I can get the content of the last message in each conversation. Do you think that is possible with LIMIT ?